# How can I use template tag inside slot in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a template that includes some HTML along with some `script` tags. I want to use it inside my vue component as a template that later I will place into the DOM and I would like it to be placed as is, so my script tags are also executed.

I would like to keep the template inside the component tag and use a `slot`.

e.g.

```
<amazing-component>
    <template>
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <script>
           console.log("I want to be executed as long as someone puts me in the DOM!");
        </script>
    </template>
</amazing-component>

<script type="text/x-template" id="component-template">
   <slot></slot>
</script>
```

But the problem is that Vue removes the `template` and the `script` tags and then replaces the `slot` tag.

What I've desperately tried so far and didn't work:

- Put the template inside another template - the template just disappears.
- Wrap the `slot` with a template - the template just disappears.
- Use a `<script type="text/x-template" >` - that was an epic failure.
- Get the slot from `$slots` - It is a VNode that doesn't have template/script tags.

The biggest problem is that the front-end doesn't have a clue of what the html inside the `template` tag looks like. It is just some html that is rendered on the server, some immutable legacy code that has to be inserted as-is in the page in order to work.

Of course I can put the template tag outside of the component and fetch it another way, but I would like to have it inside the component to keep it a bit more tidy and elegant.

Comment: template tags are *supposed* to disappear, that's the whole reason they exist.  They're a place you can hang vue rules without inserting an extra node in the DOM.

Comment: @DanielBeck you definitely have a point there, but template tags are not vue specific, so removing them completely feels kinda extreme.

Comment: That's just how Vue does it, presumably with the expectation that if you're using Vue you aren't also trying to use a separate templating system on top of it.

Comment: @xpy You can force the `<template>` tag to render as something else instead of disappearing with `<template is="div">` for example.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how Vue works. `<script>` tags do not belong in the `<template>` and are omitted for a reason. If you want something to be executed on page load, use a coresponding [hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks)

To execute server generated JS code use `eval()`

Parent.vue

```
<template>
  <child script="console.log('something')"></child>
</template>
```

Child.vue

```
<template>

</template>

<script>
  props: ['script'],
  created() {
    eval(this.script)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: My intention is not to execute some script at some point. To make it more clear, I want to have the power, with vue, to append and execute an arbitrary script tag that is constructed on the server and the front end completely ignores it's purpose, function and content.

Comment: Use `eval()` to do that. I've added an example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

While Vue consumes template tags in its own compiling, you can still force it to emit HTML template tags by using `<component is="template">`

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
      <div>
          <h1>No template:</h1>
          <template>
              test
          </template>
          <p>More code (check the page source)</p>
          <h1>Yes template: </h1>
          <component is="template">
              test
          </component>
          <p>More code(check the page source)</p>
          <h1>Yes script: </h1>
          <component is="script">
              console.log('Scrpt test');
          </component>
          <p>More code(check the console)</p>
      </div>
  `,
  data: {}
})
```

```html
<!-- development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: This is almost the same as @Archie mentioned in the comments. Sadly, the `script` tags are striped as well. :(

Comment: @xpy the problem with script tags is that its unclear what they mean, if it is ment to be executed 1 time, place the script in the body, but if it is supposed to be executed every time the component is loaded, use eval to load it, Vue is not forcing one behavior over of another when you include a script tag, but you can still force it using the same `is="script"` trick